# What are the biggest, best CPUs that support Physical Address Extension?

Tags: 64-bit, cpu, hardware-rec, lga775, pae

I'm looking for a CPU that will support PAE and fit into an LGA775 socket. This combination of technology is very much preferred for my current server hardware/software setup.

My priorities in order of highest to lowest:
PAE & LGA775
At least 1066Mhz FSB
Largest CPU cache possible
Multiple Cores if possible
HyperThreading if possible
Most other factors are of little-to-no consequence.

I'm finding it very difficult to figure out what my options are. Intel doesn't have much useful information on PAE (since x64 is so dominant), and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) simply says that "PAE is provided by Intel Pentium Pro (and above) CPUs - including all later Pentium-series processors except the 400 MHz bus versions of the Pentium M."

All of Intel's listed Pentium CPU's support Intel64, which makes me seriously doubt they will support PAE with a 32-bit OS. And Wikipedia's claim is so vague, I have no idea if they mean up-to-and-including the x64 Prescott CPUs. PAE is supposed to be an aspect of the x86 architecture, and I believe it is no longer supported in an x64 environment. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any modern Intel CPU will support PAE. Even if you don't want to use >4G of memory you need PAE if you want NX in 32 bit mode.

I still run a 32 bit Linux on a system with 8GB of RAM and a core 2 quad.

Comment: I see! So PAE does not cause my selection of CPUs to shrink. That's good news. I have a feeling that my motherboard does not support anything past the Pentium series, so I'll probably go with a Pentium E6500.

Comment: PAE causes Windows to use another addressing scheme. You can have more memory, but calculating addresses by the CPU will be a bit slower. I don't suppose it'll be very noticeable for most applications.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been the Core 2 Extremes but they aren't available any more. [**Q9650**](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819115130) should be next in line.

Answer (score 0):

> All of Intel's listed Pentium CPU's support Intel64, which makes me seriously doubt they will support PAE with a 32-bit OS.

False, in fact by definition all x86 CPUs that support x64 or even NX will support PAE with 32-bit too.